# The best loss function and optimizer to use in Keras for malware machine learning?

Tags: python, keras, syntax-error, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to find the best loss function to use in my Keras model. The model will detect malware. I am first trying to understand some practice code before I implement my own model.

I was implementing the practise code, but I then came across this error:
[image]

After some reading online, I discovered I needed to define a loss function and an optimizer. I am now unsure which would be the best loss function and optimizer to use. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I believe the code should change from:

```
model.compile(, , metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

to:

```
model.compile(loss=...,optimizer=... , metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Ps. I am new to machine learning and Keras, so don't be too harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can differ with respect to the task. I suggest you to use `Adam` and `mse` for starts, and then experiment with different ones. There is no single best loss function OR optimizer, you should really try a few ones and decide for yourself.

```
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="mse", metrics=["accuracy"])
```